# JDateChooser make action when you select date automatically only one time

Tags: java, swing, components, jdatechooser

the thing is that i'm using in Customize Code the next code:

```
DachBuscar.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener(){
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
});
```

but when i do click on the JDateChooser and i select the date, it make the action 5 times and of corse that is slower because i'm using an sql consult and that method is used 5 times, i only want to make that code 1 time, and also i thing the number of times that the method execute its more and more because i try to patch this with if and a int variable increasing each time that the method execute to use it only one time but it doesn't make effect

Comment: Can you post a more clear and direct question please?

Comment: Use the `name` of the property to determine what has actually changed or use a more appropriate listener to detect the change in state

Comment: well sorry it is something hard to explain but i used this video about the code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHoSAC6PFPg, and my problem is exacly problem is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqNPspEqCuk

Answer (score 0):

I think your DachBuscar.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener getting called multiple times,Make sure whether your method called only once.